# Javascript recursion issue

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I'm doing a CodeWarrior.com problem (this one: http://www.codewars.com/dojo/katas/521c2db8ddc89b9b7a0000c1/play/javascript).

I implemented it in python first, and my code works fine, however in Javascript, I cannot get the lines `output.push(snail(data)); return flattenArray(this.output);` to work. Calling the method in a recursive fashion seems to allow the child method to edit the variables inside the parent method.

How can I prevent this (if this is what's happening)?

Here's my code:

```
snail = function(data) {
  console.log("snail - " + data);
  this.output = [];
  // Get the top row
  this.output.push(data.splice(0,1));

  if(data.length == 0) {
    return this.output;
  }

  // Get the right row
  for(var layer=0;layer<data.length;layer++) {
    this.output.push(data[layer].splice(data[layer].length - 1,1));
  }

  // Get the bottom row
  this.output.push(data.splice(data.length - 1,1));

  // Get the left row
  for(var layer=0;layer<data.length;layer++) {
    this.output.push(data[layer].splice(0,1));
  }

  if(data.length!=0) {
    output.push(snail(data));
    return flattenArray(this.output);
  } else {
    return this.output;
  }
}

function flattenArray(arr) {
  var r = [];
  while (!arrayEqual(r, arr)) {
    r = arr;
    arr = [].concat.apply([], arr);
  }
  return arr;
}

function arrayEqual(a, b) {
  var i = Math.max(a.length, b.length, 1);
  while(i-- >= 0 && a[i] === b[i]);
    return (i === -2);
  }

function clone(obj) {
  if (null == obj || "object" != typeof obj) return obj;
  var copy = obj.constructor();
  for (var attr in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(attr)) copy[attr] = obj[attr];
  }
  return copy;
}
```

Comment: What does `this` inside your snail function mean? Should `output.push(snail(data));` be `this.output.push(snail(data));` I think you have misunderstood what `this` is here

Comment: `output.push(snail(data));` calls push on a (probably non-existent) global object named output. Since you're returning something with `this.output`, you probably want `this.output.push(snail(data));`.

Comment: I added `this.output` instead of just `output` to try and stop this problem. It doesn't seem to affect the running of the program at all.

Comment: @ToddDavies Be more specific with your comments. Added what to try to stop the problem? `this.output` instead of `output`? Is it supposed to be a global? What did you think adding `this` would do? Hard to help if you don't know what you were trying to do

Comment: Where is `snail()` getting called? Please create runnable code in http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=n5On3MPM85

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `output` variable should be local. By using `this.output`, it's being used as a global (or being shared through an object). You want it on the stack so that your recursion can work

```
snail = function (data) {
    var output = [];
```

Change all the calls to `this.output` to be `output`